# How to Add Array in Odoo 14 from XML file

Tags: arrays, xml, odoo

I want to make an Array from XML file and put a value into it, like in the example below I want to add 5 to the Array so it become [1,2,3,5]. Can someone teach me how to do it. I tried with my code below

```
<t t-set="numberArray" t-value="[1,2,3]" />
<t t-set="numberArray" t-value="numberArray.append(5)" />
<t t-esc="numberArray" />
```

But its not working and produces an error

```
TypeError: scope.numberArray.append is not a function
```

Help me please thankss

Answer (score 3):

Python list append function appends the value to the existing list, but does not return the new list as return value. Actually it returns None. This way your code will set the variable numberArray to value None when appending the number 5 to the list.

You can add the array either by using list + operator or by assigning the append return value to some other (dummy) variable.

Working solution with + operator:

```
<t t-set="numberArray" t-value="[1,2,3]" />
<t t-set="numberArray" t-value="numberArray+[5]" />
<t t-esc="numberArray" />
```

Working solution with dummy variable:

```
<t t-set="numberArray" t-value="[1,2,3]" />
<t t-set="numberArrayDummy" t-value="numberArray.append(5)" />
<t t-esc="numberArray" />
```

More info on Python list methods can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html. It states that

> You might have noticed that methods like insert, remove or sort that
> only modify the list have no return value printed – they return the
> default None. [1] This is a design principle for all mutable data
> structures in Python.

Comment: Hi, I tried your +[5] method but it becomes "[1,2,35]" the value type changed to strings now, I can't even used it to check like if 5 is in the array or not. Also tried your method with dummy but it still show the error scope.numberArray.append is not a function. Do you have any other methods?

Comment: Where and how do you use this xml "t" -element? Where do you see the error? Odoo supports t-element in QWeb templates and there the two examples work. Does the template code work in your environment without the append-part (only 1st and 3rd line in your code)?